# Channel API and appengine not good for game?

Tags: google-app-engine

- Channel Api allow pull update from server to client . But no way to send back data to socket .
  We need to make Ajax request to server , it means it very slow than send direct by socket .
- Appengine is fit for web , for socket based game ,we can't control appengine instance shutdown and restart . Game objects need to save to datastore and memcache (very slow) .
  Backend may be a acceptable solution , but i think it can't good as dedicated server for web game online .

I still looking for solution for socket  webgame on appengine

Answer (score 1):

You just answered your own question.  App Engine isn't a good platform for super low latency operations like action games.  Find another platform.  App Engine should work if latency isn't a big deal (ie turn based games).

The sockets API probably isn't going to be ideal for you either since it's for outbound sockets.

Answer (score 0):

If your game will have a small number of users then a dedicated "normal" server would be fine, of course.

If, however, you want your game to potentially scale to a far higher number of users then you have to design it accordingly and that means (probably) separating out logic (backend) and interaction with users (frontend). As you say, you don't want a server containing the only copy of the game to just shutdown. Backends won't do that.

You can sign up to the [Sockets Beta](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-appengine/m1x6sDhqx1o/discussion) which may be what you need instead of the channel API.